# Nested translating Next js 14 application using i18next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, translation, i18next

So I am trying to localize my next js 14 app using i18next lib and everything is working just fine but the nesting translation is not working for example :

> {t("components.navbar.navbarlist.home")}

it shows as it is and it should be just "Home"

here is my i18n.js:

```js
i18next
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(HttpApi)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    resources,
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
      wait: true,
    },
    supportedLngs: ["en", "ar"],
    fallbackLng: "en",
    detection: {
      order: ["path", "cookie", "htmlTag"],
      caches: ["localStorage", "cookie"],
    },
    debug: false,
    whitelist: languages,
    nsSeparator: false, // Corrected typo in your code
    keySeparator: false, // Corrected typo in your code
    backend: {
      loadPath: "./public/locales/{{lng}}/common.json", // Changed to a relative path
      crossDomain: true,
    },
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });
```

what should I provide more ? and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the `react-i18next` [library](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next). I recommend you to use the `next-i18next` [library](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next) instead since you're working on a NextJS app.

With `next-i18next`, to return objects, you have to specify that you're returning objects:

```js
const { t } = useTranslation("common");

const translated = t("components.navbar.navbarlist.home", { returnObjects: true });
```

But if the value of the key "home" is a string, this should be sufficient:

```js
const translated = t("components.navbar.navbarlist.home");
```

Check if it is nested correctly in your locale .json file.